# Copy as cURL(cmd) adds invalid characters to form data

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, postman

I want to use Postman to test server side validation so I used the browser to submit (valid) data to the server and in the network tab of Chromes developer tools used "Copy as cURL". Then, in Postman, Import->Paste Raw Text -> Import.

If I look at the request body the data appears on `x-www-form-urlencoded` tab and every value has a '`^`' character appended to it. e.g. `JobId: 75051^`

When I post it the server validation picks it up as invalid data e.g.

> The value "75051^" is not valid for JobId

**Edit**
If I use "Copy as C=cURL(bash)" instead, the `^` characters are removed but the server doesn't like the encoding used on dates and times. e.g. T

> The value '11%2F19%2F2018+12%3A15+AM' is not valid for Work Start Time

What is going on here? Can I get "Copy as cURL" to pick up my data correctly, or is there a better way to pick up the request and get it into Postman?

Comment: `^` is a cmd batch language escape symbol. It's added when you choose "Copy as cURL (cmd)". I think this is a bug in Chrome caused by the lack of understanding that the escape is not needed inside double-quoted strings. See if you can use "Copy as cURL (bash)" instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm - see my edit, it helps. But still something odd about the encoding

Comment: Might be easier to remove all those `^` especially by using a scripting utility like AutoHotkey to bind Ctrl-V to a simple string replacement on clipboard when invoked in a Postman window.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to pick up the request and get it into Postman:

1. Install the  [Postman Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related?hl=en) instead of the desktop
   app.
2. Install the [Postman Interceptor Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo/support?hl=en).
3. Open Postman and click on the Interceptor icon in the toolbar to switch the
   toggle to “on”.
4. Browse to your website: the requests appear in Postman's history.
5. Go to [Interceptor missing from native apps #1667](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1667) and vote for it

Reference:

[Postman Interceptor Extension Documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension)